# when we add dependencies gives a error Could not resolve com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3

Tags: android

when we integrate paytm SDK using add the dependencies

```
implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3') 

{  transitive = true; }
```

it gives a error

> [ Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3. ]

Cannot find any solution, have any idea please share with me.
my code sync properly with

```
implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.2')

{   transitive = true;    }
```

Difference is 1.1.2 0r 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependencies to your app level gradle dependencies

```
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

and add this to your module level gradle file

```
//using 1.2.9 as it is the latest version mentioned.
compile('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.9') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

you can check more from their github page [here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit/tree/master/Payment_Web_Sdk).

Comment: but  I add com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.2 depandencies, there is no need to add any classpath   or   in paytm doc  no any declaration regarding to classpath